# What is the minimum iOS version supported by ionic 3?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, app-store

As I got information from googling and reading on ionic official docs
[iOS 8+ should be supported](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/intro/browser-support/)
  but when I tried to download it from the app store in my device (iPhone 5) I got

[image: this app supports iOS 11.0 and above]

This means the ionic 3 apps are not supported by iOS 10. If so then is there any way to make it available for iOS 10 as well in ionic 3?

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, it seems to be the newly Content Security policy.

common symptom of apps suffering from this issue is that the app continues to work as expected on Android, uptill iOS 9 but doesn't launch / load on iOS 10.

i also havent found a way to make this work